# Can't setup Aws amplify Authentication with SSR, on Next js 13

Tags: authentication, next.js, aws-amplify, next.js13

I am trying to setup aws amplify on my next js app, with app directory to run on server side.

Here is my setup code:

```
import { Amplify } from "aws-amplify";

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const awsconfig = {
  region: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_COGNITO_REGION,
  userPoolId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID,
  userPoolWebClientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_COGNITO_USER_POOL_WEB_CLIENT_ID,
};

Amplify.configure({ Auth: awsconfig, ssr: true });

export const AwsAmplifyProvider = ({ children }: Props) => {
  return <>{children}</>;
};
```

I am always getting the error:

```
51:29.191 AuthError - 
            Error: Amplify has not been configured correctly.
```

Note: This only happens if I try to run it on the server, If I try to run the same config on the client side, using "use client", it works perfectly.

what could be the issue? What am i missing here? Thanks.